# How to rebuild index in a specific table columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How to rebuild index in a specific table columns with query? in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g. ([read manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx))

```
ALTER INDEX [index_name] ON [dbo].[MyTable] REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON);
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the table in the Object Explorer so you see the "Indexes" folder.
Right click on the "Indexes" folder and click "Rebuild All".
Alternatively, you can open the Indexes Folder and rebuild an individual index.

If you don't have a plan for identifying and rebuilding all your fragmented indexes, you can take a look at the following post:

http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/sql-server-optimization-with-index-rebuilding/

This will take you through looking at a couple of reports before and after your index rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to drop the index and recreate it.