# Rebuilding Indexes with Scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, rebuild, reindex

I'm looking for help modifying the following script or at least making sure it's correct to rebuild the indexes on a table in my database called SearchTable. I'm brand new to SQL and I don't want to destroy anything.

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + MyDatabaseName.[SearchTable] + ' REBUILD; '
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
 WHERE t.[TABLE_TYPE] = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364089/how-to-rebuild-index-in-a-specific-table-columns

Comment: alter will serve your purpose..

Comment: Do you have standard edition or just Express?

Comment: I have the Standard Edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest and safest way is to create a `Maintenance Plan`.

> Expand Management in the Object Explorer> Right click Maintenance
>   Plans> Maintenance Wizard> Create Plan for Rebuilding Indexes.

Should be straight forward. It eventually makes a Job in your server agent and then you can set a schedule or run the job manually by running this script

```
EXEC msdb..sp_start_job N'NAME OF JOB'
```

[Maintenance Plan Wizard](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189036(v=sql.105).aspx)

One thing to remember when using this technique. If you delete any tables after you create the Job/Maintenance Plan, the Plan needs to be modified to not include any deleted tables. If you don't do this, the Job will Fail. To make Edits you need to access `Management Studio` from the actual server. You cant modify Maintenance Plans remotely.

To get more information on whether the Maintenance Plan succeeded or not you can

> Right Click on Maintenance Plans > View History